# Url Pattern giving me a url mismatch error

Tags: django

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',
        WishlistRemoveView.as_view(), name='wishlist_remove'),


<form action="{% url 'wishlist_remove' pk=item.wishlistitem_set.all.0.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Remove' %}">
</form>
```

When i click on the remove button I get the following error:-

```
NoReverseMatch at /product/7/
Reverse for 'wishlist_remove' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>\\d+)/remove/$']
```

Something is wrong

Comment: For your `item`, the `wishlistitem_set` is empty...

Comment: Wow! That worked. How do I check if the item is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because for the given `item`, your `wishlistitem_set.all()` is empty, so there is no `WishlistItem` to remove.

You can make a check with:

```
{% with wishlistitems=item.wishlistitem_set.all %}
  {% if wishlistitems %}
    <form action="{% url 'wishlist_remove' pk=wishlistitems.0.pk %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Remove' %}">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

It is however a bit "odd" to only work with the first item: why should there be a button for the first item, and not the second for example?

---

> **Note**: As of [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), [**`url(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#url) is
> deprecated in favor of [**`re_path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/re-path) and has been removed in [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0).
> Furthermore a new syntax for paths has been introduced with path converters: you
> use [**`path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/path) for that.

Comment: doesnt work. I dont see the remove button. The item parameter seems to be the problem

Comment: @sly_Chandan: that is because, as already said, for that specific `item`, there are *no* related `WishlistItem`s. So then it makes no sense to have a button, for the simple reason that there is no item to remove.